# What is $\Pr(\langle \vec{a}, \vec{r} - \vec{b} \rangle \geq | \langle \vec{a}, \vec{b} \rangle | )$

Tags: probability, geometry

I am analyzing an algorithm and the following probability problem arises. Given $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in \mathbb{S}^n$ ($n$-dimensional sphere) and let $\vec{r}$ be a uniformly random unit vector through the origin, what is $$\Pr[ \;\langle \vec{a}, \vec{r} - \vec{b} \rangle \geq | \langle \vec{a}, \vec{b} \rangle | \;]$$

I have tried using that $\langle \vec{a}, \vec{b} \rangle = \cos( \theta_{a,b})$ and breaking up $ \langle \vec{a}, \vec{r} - \vec{b} \rangle $ into $\langle \vec{a}, \vec{r} \rangle + \langle \vec{a}, -\vec{b} \rangle$. Then we get the probability is equivalent to
$$ \Pr[ \; \langle \vec{a}, \vec{r} \rangle - \cos(\theta_{a,b}) \geq |\cos(\theta_{a,b})| \;]$$

However, it is at this point that I get stuck and am unsure how to simplify further, or even if it is possible to.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly if $U\in O(n+1)$ is orthogonal, then $U(\vec r)$ has uniform distribution on the sphere.

Therefore $\text{P}(\langle \vec a, \vec r - \vec b\rangle \geq |\langle \vec a, \vec b\rangle|)= \text{P}(r_1 \geq |\langle\vec a, \vec b\rangle|+\langle \vec a, \vec b\rangle)$ by taking orthogonal $U$ with $U(\vec a) = \vec e_1$, where of course, $\vec e_1, ..., \vec e_{n+1}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

So it suffices to find distribution of a coordinate of $\vec r$.

So $n$-dimensional area of $S_t = \{\vec x\in \mathbb{S}^n : x_1\geq t\}$ for each $t$ (or at least, $t\geq 0$).

Then we'll have $\text{P}(\langle \vec a, \vec r - \vec b\rangle \geq |\langle \vec a, \vec b\rangle|)= \text{Area}(S_{|\langle\vec a, \vec b\rangle|+\langle \vec a, \vec b\rangle})$.